# Delete duplicate records that do not exist in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 table EnquiryMaster and Requirement.
I want to delete the duplicate Company from the table EnquiryMaster whose enqiryid do not exist in Requirement table

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EnquiryMaster](
[EnquiryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[orgid] [int] NULL,
[uid] [int] NULL,
[Company] [varchar](160) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[HeadOfficeAddress] [varchar](460) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_EnquiryMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
[EnquiryId] ASC
     )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Requirement](
[RequirementID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[uid] [int] NULL,
[orgid] [int] NULL,
[EnquiryID] [int] NULL,
[Company] [varchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Requirement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
     (
[RequirementID] ASC
     )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
     ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: do you mean you want to delete duplicate Company or the whole row from EnquiryMaster table where EnquiryID does not exist in Requirement?

Comment: Whole row of the record that is duplicated

Comment: i have 2 rows with company "Infosys". I  want to delete 1 and keep only that whose enquiry id is not in requirement table

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[EnquiryMaster]
WHERE [EnquiryId] NOT IN 
(SELECT [EnquiryID] FROM [dbo].[Requirement])
```

But it is not clear why you call such rows as duplicates.

**UPD.** Considering duplicates.

```
DELETE T1
FROM dbo.EnquiryMaster T1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.EnquiryMaster T2
    WHERE T1.Company = T2.Company AND T1.EnquiryId <> T2.EnquiryId
) AND T1.EnquiryId NOT IN (
    SELECT EnquiryID
    FROM dbo.Requirement
)
```

Comment: i have 2 rows with company "Infosys" in EnquiryMaster table. I want to delete 1 and keep only that whose enquiry id is in requirement table

Answer (score 0):

Delete from EnquiryMaster E1 where exist(select 1 from EnquiryMaster E2 
where E1.Company = E2.Company and E1.EnquiryId<>E2.EnquiryId)
and E1.EnquiryId Not In(select EnquiryId from Requirement)