# sql show duplicate rows missing from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

in sql server basically I have a query to find duplicates in one table.  I want to filter this list down to all the duplicates that appear in the one table and are not contained in the second table

to get duplicates:

```
select   [OBId], COUNT(*) AS dupes  
FROM         [Broker] b
  GROUP BY [OBId]  
  HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

broker has id,OBId

and I want all the duplicates that don't have a brokerid in this table
second table
[image: test]

I tried to do a subquery but I couldn't figure it out

Comment: This is very nearly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19538507/delete-duplicate-records-that-do-not-exist-in-other-table -- my guess is that if you read the second answer there you will get what you need to get you moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you simply use a subquery and say this

```
select [OBId], 
COUNT(*) AS dupes  
FROM [Broker] b
WHERE [OBId] NOT IN (select other_table_id from other_table)
GROUP BY [OBId]  
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a NOT EXISTS in a subquery:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM 
    (SELECT [OBId]
        , COUNT(*) AS dupes  
    FROM [Broker] b
    GROUP BY [OBId]  
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) sub
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM SomeSecondTable sst
    WHERE sub.OBId = BrokerId);
```

If you are trying to return the full set of records from the Broker table for the duplicates and you want to suppress the records that don't exist in the second table, then you could use this code:

```
SELECT sub.*
FROM [Broker] b
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT [OBId]
        , COUNT(*) AS dupes  
    FROM [Broker] sb
    WHERE b.OBId = sb.OBId
    GROUP BY [OBId]
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
AND NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM SomeSecondTable sst
    WHERE b.OBId = BrokerId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `EXCEPT` clause:

```
select   [OBId]
FROM     [Broker] b
  GROUP BY [OBId]  
  HAVING   (COUNT(*) > 1)

EXCEPT

select   [OBId]
FROM     [SecondTable] T2
```